# Grails ClassNotFoundException com.google.common.collect.Maps

Tags: grails, classnotfoundexception

I need some help, I am trying to make an controller using Google Analytics API, but using:

```
statsController.groovy
/**************************************************************/

import com.google.gdata.client.analytics.AnalyticsService

class StatsController {

 def myService

 def stats(){

   myService = new AnalyticsService("example-App");
 }

}

/************************************************************/
```

error Message:

> ClassNotFoundException occurred when processing request: [...]
>   com.google.common.collect.Maps

I ve tryed adding to the buildpath the "gdata.analytics*.jar", "google-collect-1.0.jar", "guava.jar" and "jsr305.jar" but without results, the error always says that i described or NotDefClassError ocurred when processing request: [...] com.google.gdata.client.analytics.AnalyticsService.

I need to solve.

Comment: Do you find your JARs in the deployed war/ear file?

Comment: my WAR file, havent mys JAR files, im searched in WARFILE/WEB-INF/lib, i surpose that its the site where libs would be. why there isnt? thanks for respond hims056

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The handling of JARs is kept pretty easy in grails. If you don't use stuff like maven you can just copy your JARs into the lib folder in the root directory of your grails application. 
Try to put them there and see if it solves the problem.

Further: what IDE do you use? IntelliJ for instance recognize JARs within the lib folder instantly. So you should see the effects in your IDE already.

Comment: im using STS, i had push my JARs files in the root of Grails projets, at lib folder, and i added it to the build path, doing this, the error is the next:     java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
Message
    Could not initialize class com.google.gdata.client.analytics.AnalyticsService

Comment: Seems like either you have JAR incompatibilities or the JARs are still missing.
I would recommend to remove all related JARs, then download the gdata-sec..zip from [here](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/downloads/list) - This is the jar that contains com.google.gdata.client.analytics.AnalyticsService.
Fianlly, look for java/lib/gdata-analytics*.jar and copy them to your lib folder. 
After deployment they need to be in the WEB-INF/lib folder.
By the way: Waht does Eclipse say, can it resolve the class?

Comment: Christopher thanks for your atention, i had downloaded the zip file that you say, and copied the 2 JARs for analytics "gdata-analytics-2.1.jar" and "gdata-analytics-meta-2.1.jar" into grailsProject/lib , the error is diferent, now is the next:     java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
Message
    com.google.common.collect.Maps, i had been this error yesterday, i have in lib and into buildpath "gdata-collect-1.0-rc1.jar". eclipse cant resolve the class

Comment: OK, at least something changed :-)
Now it looks like you are missing a dependency.
See [this site](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/wiki/Dependencies), in particular the [google-collections.jar](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/). **EDIT** Sorry, it is now called [guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), as you already recognized. 
Re-download this an put it in your lib folder as well.
Your IDE should hopefully stop to complain then.

Comment: i have agregate to my lib dir all jars, added to the buildpath but in the generated WAR file WEB-INF/lib it isnt, i think than we are skiping a configuration step. is necesary that in the lib directory of the WAR file must to be my JARs files?

Comment: There is no need (in the default cases) to configure any buildpath manually. During the war-creation grails is setting the paths automatically.
How do you create the war anyway?
So what I would suggest:
1. grails clean 2. grails war 3. unzip an double check what's inside the WEB-INF/lib folder.

Comment: after that use clean command in grails the WAR has my JARs, but the exception is the same: Class
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
Message
    Could not initialize class com.google.gdata.client.analytics.AnalyticsService

Comment: Ok, so the grails clean was at least successfull. So I assume the message does not mean that AnalyticsService could not be found, but one of its dependencies.
I've read that Analytics [requires a bunch of JARs](http://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-analytics-data-export-api/RypbDkH_9yE). Do you have all of them included?

Comment: before that post here i have been searching about my error about 8 hours, i had seen that dependency list yet, i have all jars on my buildpath now (i tryed yesterday adding that JARs unsucessful) but my error has changed, now it say     java.lang.NoSuchMethodError
Message
    com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet.copyOf([Ljava/lang/Object;)Lcom/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet; the first time that i try but if i refresh my browser with F5 key, the error changes and say NoClassDefFoundError ...

Comment: Crap. Unfortunately I can't think of any other problems than dependency problems - because, obviously, this is what your application is complaining. I would try to reduce your problem to the basics. Means: 1) Create a new project 2) Put all the mentioned JARs into the lib folder 3) Run a grails clean 4) run grails war 5) See if problem still exists.
Sorry for the unsatisfying answer.

Comment: dont worry, your info was very helpfull for me, i have been reading and look like that the jar google-collect is deprecated and give stranges errors, i unlinked it from my project and the error that now i have is more easy it is:     java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
Message
    com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential i think that i ve to add a new library

Comment: Ah, interesting. I currently work with OAuth2 authentication. Not for Analytics, but for Android. For my project I need following JARs
- google-api-client-1.11.0-beta
- google-api-client-appengine-1.11.0-beta.jar
- google-api-services-androidpublisher-v1-rev2-1.8.0-beta.jar
- google-http-client-1.11.0-beta.jar
- google-http-client-appengine-1.11.0-beta.jar
- google-http-client-jackson-1.11.0-beta.jar
- google-oauth-client-1.11.0-beta.jar
- google-oauth-client-appengine-1.11.0-beta.jar
- google-oauth-client-servlet-1.11.0-beta.jar

Comment: i have imported all JARs (no that androids uses), with no results, stay the same ClassNotFoundException

Comment: Finally i solved my problem, i have imported all the libs http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Setup#Download_Library_with_Dependencies and it is working ok. Thanks for your help Christopher

Comment: What an interminable process.. but great.